# Is $S_m:=\{m\sqrt2 - [m\sqrt2] : m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ dense in $[0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Here $[m]:=$greatest integer value less than $m$.

Now for any real no say, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $m\le a\lt m+1$

Hence $0\le a-m\lt 1$, So $\forall k\in S_m$, $0\le k\lt 1$

When $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s\neq t$, $S_s\neq S_t$, Hence $S_m$ in a infinite set.

Let $r\gt 0$, We subdivide the interval $[0,1)$ into $k$ equal parts such that length of the each interval is less than $r$. Since our set in infinite at least any sub interval must contain two distinct element say $p,q$. Without loss of generality assume $p\lt q$,

Which implies $0\le p-q\lt r$,  $p-q\in S_m$

Hence $B(0,r)\cap S_m\neq\emptyset$

I don't know how to procced further, or is the given set not dense?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: sorry,I am not familiar with this site

Comment: First of all, about notation: the symbol $S_m$ for your set doesn't really make sense, because $m$ isn't some fixed parameters, it's quantified over in the definition of the set. You should just write $S$. At a later point you write $S_s\neq S_t$, by which it seems you mean to define $S_n=n\sqrt2-[n\sqrt2]$, a function on the integers. Let's agree to write $s(n)=n\sqrt2-[n\sqrt2]$ and $S=\{s(n)|n\in\mathbb Z\}$, this is better notation.

Comment: Second of all, your proof doesn't make sense to me. First you claim without proof that $s$ is an injective function, which is probably true but it isn't obvious to me. Then your argument below that doesn't make sense. If you subdivide $[0, 1]$ into subintervals, the fact that $S$ is infinite certainly does not imply that $S$ must intersect one of those subintervals, and also the fact that $p,q\in S$ does not imply $p-q\in S$ as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Yeah u r crct, I messed up with the notation

Comment: Yeah p-q need not be$\in$S

Comment: I was in the proof n+m$\sqrt2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, in between I faced this scenario, so I had a doubt whether I is dense

Comment: This is known as [Kroneckers Approximation Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html)